# Try to draw a line with abline?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

```
ggplot(G, aes(x = State, y = Score, fill = State)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "identity", width = 0.5) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) + 
    coord_flip()
```

This the code I am using and I am trying to add a line at the score of 236 so how to do it and how to improve the chart in general and any edit or suggestion are always welcome.

[image: Here]

Comment: Just `geom_hline` really, e.g. `ggplot(data.frame(state = state.abb, area = state.area), aes(state, area, fill = state)) + geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) + geom_hline(yintercept = 1e4, color = 'red') + scale_y_log10() + coord_flip()`

Comment: @alistaire Shouldn't it be `geom_vline`? The OP says the line should be `"at the score of 236"`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas No, because of `coord_flip`

Comment: @alistaire OK, sorry for the noise, I hadn't noticed it.

Comment: As for to improve of the chart, you should probably rank your states in the increasing order (to help comparisons), remove the colours (it does not mean anything) , consider shortening the bars, and simplify the background (the grey background is nice for scatterplot, but you do not need it for bar plots!).

Comment: I'd like to add that `fill = Score` might look nice as you'll have a color gradient showing an increase in score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
geom_hline(yintercept = 236)
```

Might be worth while to reorder your y axis and use `fill = Score`. It would make the plot look something like this:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(State, -Assault), Assault, fill = Assault)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.75, aes(fill = Assault)) +
  labs(x = "State") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 200, size = 1) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `geom_vline()` to do this. Since you have so many bars you will want to apply the vline after your `geom_bar()` so that it will show up on top of your bars (rather than underneath where you can only barely see it).

```
ggplot(G, aes(x = State, y = Score, fill = State)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "identity", width = 0.5) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept=236, color="#000000", linetype="solid") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) + 
    coord_flip()
```

All I've done there is add the third line to your example above. `ggplot2` always confuses me with horizontal and vertical especially when you do things like `coord_flip()`. I think I've got it correct (even though it looks wrong it's because of the flip), but if I'm mistaken and the line comes out horizontal replace that third line above with this:

```
geom_vline(xintercept=236, color="#000000", linetype="solid") +
```

and note the only two changes, which are that vline becomes hline and xintercept becomes yintercept.